# JavaScript FileReader returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, base64, blob, png, filereader

I was trying to Base64 encode a user-provided file with JS. This is my code:

```
let image = document.getElementById('image').files[0];
if (!image) {
    alert('No images have been provided!');
    return;
}
let blob = new Blob([image], { type: 'image/png' });
let reader = new FileReader;
reader.addEventListener('load', loadEvent => {
    let base64EncodedImage = reader.result
        .replace('data:', '');
});
```

Problem is that `reader.readAsDataURL(blob)` always returns `undefined`.

Comment: Does `reader.readAsDataURL(blob)` itself return `undefined`, or is `base64EncodedImage` `undefined`? The former is meant to return `undefined`, the data is available in the `load` event callback.